# Android M exact alarms?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

i recently upgraded my phone to android m and i am trying to get my alarm app working. I have always been using set and setExact to schedule my alarms but now in android m they seems to be obsolete.

I have tried setExactAndAllowIdle and setAlarmClock and they work fine when the alarm is set maximum about an hour into the future but when i set the alarms further into the future(for example the next morning) they are newer executed.

How do i implement the same functionality in android m?
My Alarm Register Below.

```
package com.lindev.newday.legacy;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.os.Build;

public class NDLegacyAlarmHelper {

public static NDLegacyAlarmRegisterMethod RegisterAlarm(long time, PendingIntent pendingIntent, AlarmManager alarmManager)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        //alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClock = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClock, pendingIntent);
        return NDLegacyAlarmRegisterMethod.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle;
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        return NDLegacyAlarmRegisterMethod.setExact;
    }
    else
    {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        return NDLegacyAlarmRegisterMethod.set;
    }
}
}
```